# How many memory copies occur when I read from TCP socket

Tags: c, tcp, kernel, nic

My application runs `read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0)`. I know the kernel needs to do some copy work behind the scene. How many memory copies occur when `buffer` is allocated on the stack, and will it change if `buffer` is allocated on the heap?

Thanks.

Comment: That really depends. Which kernel are we talking about? Which version of it?

Comment: `read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0)`???  **FOUR** parameters?  [`read()` takes three](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html): `ssize_t read( int, void *, size_t );`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't believe there is difference between heap or stack memory in number of copies. But I do believe there is difference between versions (which I don't understand as question he wants). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of memory copies is always the same no matter if buffer is on *heap* or *stack*. Difference is only where is the memory located where you copy your data.

In case of stack, you can enter to stack overflow and your program will have undefined behavior while if you do it on heap, you can enter to memory leaks if you don't free your memory after you don't need it anymore.